# Bash prompt: How to invert text white-on-black instead of black-on-white like tcsh

Tags: bash, colors, prompt, tcsh, csh

I'm a current `tcsh` user and have this setting in my `.tcshrc` file to set the prompt:

```
set prompt="%S MBP %s %~ [\!] "
```

My screen's text is usually black text on white brackground, but the `%S` turns on white-on-black mode which the `%s` turns it back to black-on-white. See below:

[image]

Now I'm on `bash`. How do I set the same prompt to use inverted white-on-black and vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tcsh doesn't set any specific colors – it uses the "inverted colors" mode that swaps foreground and background, whichever those may be.

Bash doesn't have terminfo integration, so you'll need to get the correct escape sequences through an external binary... (tput comes with ncurses)

```
\[$(tput smso)\]
\[$(tput rmso)\]
```

...or hardcode them directly, as they're the same in 99% of terminals currently in use – reverse is CSI 7 and unreverse is CSI 27:

```
\[\e[7m\]
\[\e[27m\]
```

The `\[` and `\]` brackets aren't part of the actual sequence, instead they tell bash's line-editing code (readline) that this part of your PS1 *is* in fact a formatting sequence and doesn't advance the cursor. Any "invisible" parts of your prompt must be marked this way, otherwise the edited text won't redraw correctly.

```
PS1="\[\e[7m\] MBP \[\e[27m\] \w [\!] "
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a reference for those sequences, `smso`, `CSI 7`, `7m`?

Comment: http://rtfm.etla.org/xterm/ctlseq.html is a good start. (CSI means `\e[`, so the reverse code is either `\e[7m` or "CSI 7 m".)

Comment: Thanks. I used to do `curses` programming on Unix back in the day, but that's long out of my head.